# npm run build command fails

Tags: node.js, quip, liveapps

I am trying to build the quip gdrive live app example from quip.  Following the quip liveapps instructions https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/1.x.x/guide/getting-started/ and when I run the npm run build command I get an error "NODE_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am running windows 10, python 3.9 installed Node.js 14.16.1 from the website link in https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/1.x.x/guide/getting-started/ .

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolving this?

Thank you

Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows still has some tweaks necessary, if you look in `package.json` in the `scripts` field you'll see the run command, which probably looks something like `NODE_ENV=development webpack` - you can just remove the `NODE_ENV=development` part since windows doesn't allow assigning environment variables that way.

Comment: Very helpful thank you .  There seems to be a lot of tweaking if you are using windows might be easier to use a linux vm :-)